# Unable to download jre automatically in Mozilla Firefox, but working fine in IE

Tags: html, applet, mozilla, java

I am unable to download JRE automatically in Mozilla Firefox, but it works well with IE.
The target is for the user to be able to have a JRE without searching for it by himself.

```
< OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
        width="5" height="5"
 codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4_2-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,2,0">
 < param name="code" value="xyz.pack1.myclass">
 < param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.4.2">
 < param name="archive" value="abc.jar">
  < COMMENT>
    < EMBED type="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.4.2"
    width="5" height="5"
           archive="abc.jar"
           java_CODE="xyz.pack1.myclass"
           pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/download.html">
    < NOEMBED>
  < /COMMENT> No support found for JDK 1.4.2 applets!
      < /NOEMBED>
    < /EMBED>
< /OBJECT>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why this is being down-voted... Seems like a legitimate problem. Perhaps they misunderstand you and thought you were just trying to download the JRE manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the problem could be within your installation of firefox.
There are multiple reasons why firefox will not load the jre (e.G. if he already has one or something is hindering him actively).

Try to get a clean Firefox installation on a clean machine, preferably one you just installed and there, test it again.

Then it could be that Firefox doesn't know what a cab file is (though this is unlikely) and is refusing to call it. To test that open the cab file in your Firefox, if the save file dialog appears and does not provide you with a possibility to open the file (instead of saving it) that could be the problem.

What Windows are you using and have you tested it on other ones?

Good luck with this one.